# Whydoes Vue3 Toastify fails to recognise the toast object they explicitly state we should use?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, toast

I'm using a vue3 package to handle my toast notifications called vue3.toastify

the [documentation clearly states](https://vue3-toastify.js-bridge.com/usage/replace-default-transition.html) that if I want to change default transitions globally i must do this:

```
app.use(
  Vue3Toasity,
  {
    transition: toast.TRANSITIONS.FLIP,
    // toast.TRANSITIONS.BOUNCE
    // toast.TRANSITIONS.ZOOM
    // toast.TRANSITIONS.SLIDE
  }, // as ToastContainerOptions
);
```

However if I do this the apps throws an error

```
app.js:1212 Uncaught ReferenceError: toast is not defined
    at eval (main.js:29:1)
    at ./src/main.js (app.js:294:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:1209:33)
    at app.js:2389:109
    at __webpack_require__.O (app.js:1255:23)
    at app.js:2390:53
    at app.js:2392:12
```

I'm doing it form my main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

import ClickOutside from "./directives/clickOutside.js";
import hapticDirective from "./directives/hapticDirective.js";

import Vue3Toasity from 'vue3-toastify';
import 'vue3-toastify/dist/index.css';

console.log(Vue3Toastify);

createApp(App)
    .directive("haptic", hapticDirective)
    .directive("click-outside", ClickOutside)
    .use(store)
    .use(router)
    .use(
        Vue3Toasity,
        { 
            closeButton: false,
            containerClassName: 'toast-container-class',
            toastClassName: 'toast-class',
            bodyClassName: 'toast-body-class',
            progressClassName: 'progress-bar',
            autoClose: 30000,
            transition: toast.TRANSITIONS.BOUNCE,   // this doesn't work :(        
            style: {
              opacity: '1',
              userSelect: 'initial',
            },
        })
    .mount('#app')
```

It works if i do it local, from my child component Login.vue

```
const registerWithGoogle = async () => {
      error.value = null;
      success.value = null;
      const auth = getAuth();
      const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
      try {
        const userCredential = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
        console.log(userCredential.user);
        await store.dispatch("logInStateCommit", {
          user: userCredential.user,
        });

        success.value = "You're in!";
        router.push("/dashboard");
      } catch (err) {
        handleAuthError(err);
      }
    };

    const handleAuthError = (err) => {
      console.error(err.message);
      switch (err.code) {
        case "auth/invalid-email":
          error.value =
            "The email address provided is not in a valid format. Please enter a valid email address.";
          break;
       
        case "auth/missing-password":
          error.value = "Please type your password";
          break;

        case "auth/unauthorized-domain":
          error.value =
            "You can't login using an authentication provider form this specific domain";
          break;
        default:
          error.value =
            "An unknown error has occurred. Please try again later or contact support for assistance";
          break;
      }
      toast.error(error.value, {
        transition: toast.TRANSITIONS.BOUNCE, // this works
      });
    };
```

Is anyone able to help me?
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved. I needed to import the 'toast' on my main.js

```
import Vue3Toasity, {toast} from 'vue3-toastify';
```